# Windows IoT Core RaspPi Walkie Talkie

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to use a few Rasp Pi Board for a local network audio broadcast with one RaspPi as main(broadcast) and the rest as slave (receiver) like walkie talkie.
I have looked up for example such as `[WebCam App][1]` but it seems like the audio is recorded first before playback.
Is there any sample I could refer to for my application where the audio input is captured and live stream to the respective slave device.
Thanks.

Comment: There is an API(StartRecordToStreamAsync) in [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture#methods) that can record to a random-access stream for later access. Do you want to playback real-time or send the recorded stream out real-time?

Comment: Hi @RitaHan-MSFT I am looking for both real-time playback & stream out real-time. Real-time playback would playback via my USB audio adapter to a local speaker. Stream out real-time will be streaming to the slave devices (receivers).

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample of recording and handling and sending the live stream of the WebCam. You can reference it and modify it for your use case.

[HttpWebcamLiveStream](https://github.com/SaschaIoT/HttpWebcamLiveStream/tree/6f58a92741663c7bc0c53f0b4826099852178932)

It also uses MediaCapture API. You can set to audio recording, for example, like this:

```
            mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            var settings = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            settings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
            settings.MediaCategory = Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCategory.Communications;
            settings.AudioProcessing = Windows.Media.AudioProcessing.Raw;
            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
```

This sample also shows how to implement an HTTP server so that it can send the live stream data to other clients.